# Sed - delete line with multiple special characters using a variable

Tags: linux, sed

I'm having the following file:

- test.txt

which contains:

```
3;/var/tmp/test.mp4
3;/var/tmp/test2.mp4
1;/var/tmp/test3.mp4
```

I need to remove for example "**3;/var/tmp/test2.mp4**" using a variable.

```
string="3;/var/tmp/test2.mp4"
sed -i '#$string#d' test.txt
```

Does not throw any errors but I can't seem to get the line deleted...
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape the first delimiter if different than `/` in the address.

Also if you use variables then you have to expose them to the shell (with double quotes to avoid problems with blanks).

```
sed -i "\#$string#d" test.txt
```

or

```
sed -i '\#'"$string"'#d' test.txt
```